# mongodb currentop output "secs_running", "microsecs_running" values doesn't match

Tags: mongodb

I'm checking currentOp.

```js
db.getSiblingDB("admin").
  .aggregate([ { $currentOp: {} } ])
```

Each document shows "secs_running" and "microsecs_running", which according to the manual, shows the duration of the operation since it started.

```
    ...
    "secs_running": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "microsecs_running": {
        "$numberLong": "32178"
    },
   ...

    // another operation
    ...
    "secs_running": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "microsecs_running": {
        "$numberLong": "273420"
    },
    ...
```

As far as I know, 32178 microseconds is 32.178 seconds. I see in many other outputs "secs_running" and "microsecs_running" values do not match. Am I missing something?

Comment: 32178 microseconds is 32.178 milliseconds, or 0.032178 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug in software itself  with incorrect use of `struct timeval` or platform-specific issue with certain kernel builds related to `struct timespec` able to contain values greater than 1000000000 for nanoseconds (which pretty much means that your OS is something exotic). That's a lot of "ifs" involved.